# Show that there does not exist a sequence $(a_n)_{n\ge1}$ of positive integers such that $a_{n-1}\le (a_{n+1}-a_n)^2\le a_n$, $\forall n\ge 2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, inequality

> Show that there does not exist a sequence $(a_n)_{n\ge1}$ of positive integers such that $a_{n-1}\le (a_{n+1}-a_n)^2\le a_n$, $\forall n\ge 2$.

---

**My Proof**: Call $d_n=a_{n+1}-a_n$; then from the given conditions we get, $$\sqrt{a_{n-1}} \leq d_n \leq \sqrt{a_n}$$ and $$\sqrt{a_{n}} \leq d_{n+1} \leq \sqrt{a_{n+1}}$$ Subtracting these, we get, $$d_{n+1}-d_n \leq \sqrt{a_{n+1}}-\sqrt{a_n} \quad \text{(we only took upper bound into account)}$$ $$ \implies a_{n+2}+ a_n \leq \sqrt{a_{n+1}}-\sqrt{a_n} \implies a_n + \sqrt{a_n} \leq \sqrt{a_{n+1}} - a_{n+2} \implies a_{n+2} \leq \sqrt{a_{n+1}} \implies a_{n+2}^2 \leq a_{n+1}$$ But also, $a_{n+1}^2 \leq a_{n+2}^2$. Hence $$a_{n+1}^2 \leq a_{n+2}^2 \leq a_{n+1} \implies a_{n+1}=a_{n+2}=1$$ Inductively, we get $a_i= 1 \quad \forall \quad i=1,2,3, \cdots$. but from the condition given in the problem, $1 \leq  (1-1)^2 \leq 1$ is wrong. Hence, there is no such sequence of natural numbers.
**My concern** about my solution is that it feels very loose to me, I think I didn't use the lower bound to its full ability, so I would like to know if there is any fault in my solution.

Comment: $a<b$ and $c<d$ does not imply $c-a<d-b$ so the line after "Substracting these" is wrong.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek With the constraints that $a<c$ and $b<d$, would it be true?

Comment: $a>b$ and $c<d$ implies $c-a<d-b$. You can always add inequalities, but multiplying by $-1$ reverts the direction.

Comment: @Graphs-circles Welcome to Math SE. FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24a_%7Bn-1%7D%5Cle(a_%7Bn%2B1%7D-a_n)%5E2%5Cle%20a_n%24&p=1), there's the AoPS threads [a_(n-1) <= (a_(n+1)-a_(n))^2 <= a_n, no sequence of naturals](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2391344p19627172) and [Sequences and Functional Equations](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1771890p11631133).

Comment: I'd recommend the first link by John Omelian for now until the doubts in [this related post from today also](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4745900/1104384) are figured out. For the first one, the only thing I'd add is that it uses the inequality $\sqrt{x + \sqrt{x}} < \sqrt{x} + \frac{1}{2}$, which you obtain by squaring both sides and developing the RHS's square.

Comment: In addition to Michal Adamaszek's point, $d_{n+1}-d_n = (a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}) - (a_{n+1}-a_n) = a_{n+2} + a_n - 2a_{n+1}$, not $a_{n+2} + a_n$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose contrarily that $a_1,a_2,...$ are positive integers such that $a_{n-1}\leqslant(a_{n+1}-a_n)^2\leqslant a_n\;$ ($n=2,3,...$ ). These inequalities may be written
$$a_n+\surd a_{n-1}\leqslant a_{n+1}\leqslant a_n+\surd a_n\quad(n=2,3,...).\qquad(1\text{a,b})$$
Since $(\surd a_n+\frac12)^2-\frac14=a_n+\surd a_n\geqslant a_{n+1}$ (by ineq. $1$b), taking the square root gives $\surd a_n+\frac12>\surd a_{n+1}$. Now lowering the index by $1$ yields $\surd a_{n-1}>\surd a_n-\frac12\;$ ($n=3,4,...$ ). Combining this with ineq. $1$a, we obtain
$$a_n+\surd a_n-\tfrac12<a_{n+1}\leqslant a_n+\surd a_n\quad(n=3,4,...),$$
where the second inequality is ineq. $1$b. Because all the $a_k$ are integers, it follows that
$$(\text{recursion rule})\qquad\quad a_{n+1}=a_n+\lfloor\surd a_n\rfloor,\qquad (\text{R})$$
$$(\text{root-floor bound})\qquad\;\surd a_n<\lfloor\surd a_n\rfloor+\tfrac12,\qquad(\text{B})$$
for $n=3,4,...$.

We now develop some conditional lower bounds for $a_3$, $a_4$, and $a_5$, in four steps.

(Step $1$) $\;$ If $a_3\geqslant m^2$, for some integer $m$, then $a_4\geqslant m^2+m$ by rule R.

(Step $2$) $\;$ If $a_4\geqslant m^2+m$, then rule R gives $a_5\geqslant m^2+m+\lfloor\surd(m^2+m)\rfloor\geqslant m^2+2m$. However,
$$m+\tfrac12<\surd(m^2+2m)<m+1,$$
so that $a_5\neq m^2+2m$ by bound B. Consequently $a_5\geqslant m^2+2m+1=(m+1)^2$.

(Step $3$) $\;$ If $a_5\geqslant(m+1)^2$, then $a_4+\lfloor\surd a_4\rfloor\geqslant(m+1)^2$ by rule R. We cannot have $a_4\leqslant m^2+m$, because that would give $$a_5\leqslant m^2+m+\lfloor\surd(m^2+m)\rfloor=m^2+2m<(m+1)^2.$$ Hence $a_4\geqslant m^2+m+1=(m+\tfrac12)^2+\tfrac34,$
and so $\surd a_4\geqslant m+\tfrac12$. But bound B prohibits this unless $\surd a_4\geqslant m+1$. Therefore the latter inequality must hold, and $a_4\geqslant(m+1)^2$.

(Step $4$) $\;$ By reasoning analogous to that of Step $3$, if $a_4\geqslant(m+1)^2$, then $a_3\geqslant(m+1)^2$.

Clearly $a_3\geqslant1^2$ and, by collapsing Steps $1$ to $4$, we see that $a_3\geqslant m^2$ implies $a_3\geqslant(m+1)^2$, for arbitrary $m$. Consequently $a_3\geqslant n^2$ for all integers $n$, which is an impossibility: the supposed sequence does not exist.