# Show that there does not exist a sequence $(a_n)_{n\ge1}$ of positive integers such that $a_{n-1}\le (a_{n+1}-a_n)^2\le a_n$, $\forall n\ge 2$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality

> Show that there does not exist a sequence $(a_n)_{n\ge1}$ of positive integers such that $a_{n-1}\le (a_{n+1}-a_n)^2\le a_n$, $\forall n\ge 2$.

---

I have found a solution of this problem [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1771890p11636661).
The solution goes as follows:

> if exists then,
> we have, $a_n+\sqrt{a_n}\ge a_{n+1}\ge a_n+\sqrt{a_{n-1}}$.
> so, either,$\sqrt{a_n}-\sqrt{a_{n-1}}\ge 1$ which means,
> $a_n\ge 1+a_{n-1}+2\sqrt{a_{n-1}}..(1)$.
> Again, $a_{n-1}+\sqrt{a_{n-1}}\ge a_n...(2)$
> So, $(1),(2)$ together gives a contradiction.
> Or, we must have, $a_n=m^2$ for some $m$ which again leads to a contradiction.
> Thus, no such sequence exists

---

My doubts are:

1. The person suggests from the expression $$a_n+\sqrt{a_n}\ge a_{n+1}\ge a_n+\sqrt{a_{n-1}}$$ we get two possibilities that are, either $\sqrt{a_n}-\sqrt{a_{n-1}}\ge 1$ or $a_n=m^2$.
   How does that expression suggests these two possibilities?
2. Why is $\sqrt{a_n}-\sqrt{a_{n-1}}\ge 1$?

Comment: **Dupe** of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4745794/242) from 4 hours ago.

Comment: @BillDubuque I don't know, one is about verifying their own proof and the other about doubts on the proof of someone else, the two posts are somewhat different in what the answers would be in theory to be honest. That said, having them linked to each other is still good since the initial premise is the exact same problem I guess?

Comment: @BillDubuque Hello, that was indeed my post from another account, but I didn't want to edit that post, as the intention of these 2 post are quite different, despite having the same problem as described by Bruno B. I hope this is ok.